# Error in ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Tags: java, arrays, runtime-error, indexoutofboundsexception

I got a error in  `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0`, So how to avoid this error?

```
package javaapplication1;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Url {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(args[0]);
            System.out.println("URL is " + url.toString());
            System.out.println("protocol is "
                    + url.getProtocol());
            System.out.println("authority is "
                    + url.getAuthority());
            System.out.println("file name is " + url.getFile());
            System.out.println("host is " + url.getHost());
            System.out.println("path is " + url.getPath());
            System.out.println("port is " + url.getPort());
            System.out.println("default port is "
                    + url.getDefaultPort());
            System.out.println("query is " + url.getQuery());
            System.out.println("ref is " + url.getRef());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

### ERROR:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at javaapplication1.Url.main(Url.java:10) Java Result: 1
```

Comment: Are you passing any command line arguments to your app?  (ie. args[0] is throwing the exception because there is nothing in the array)

Comment: args array is empty...

Comment: To avoid the error, don't reference an array element that doesn't exist.

Comment: Would anyone who wishes to down-vote this *please* leave a reason.  I find the down-vote quite mystifying.

Answer (score 2):

This error happen because argument array passed to java program has no element or no arugment is passed to program, to avoid this make a check before using its value

```
if(args.length > 0) {
    // do your task
}
```

then your amin will be

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if(args.length > 0) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(args[0]);
            System.out.println("URL is " + url.toString());
            System.out.println("protocol is "
                    + url.getProtocol());
            System.out.println("authority is "
                    + url.getAuthority());
            System.out.println("file name is " + url.getFile());
            System.out.println("host is " + url.getHost());
            System.out.println("path is " + url.getPath());
            System.out.println("port is " + url.getPort());
            System.out.println("default port is "
                    + url.getDefaultPort());
            System.out.println("query is " + url.getQuery());
            System.out.println("ref is " + url.getRef());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the error you have to check the length of the array *args* before accessing the index 0 of this array.
In most cases it is a good idea to print some usage message and exit with a certain error code.

```
if (args.length != 1)
{
   System.err.println("Wrong number of arguments!");
   System.err.println("Usage: java javaapplication1.Url <URL>");
   int errorcode = -1; // choose an appropriate number here!
   System.exit(errorcode);
}
// now you can be sure that the args has exactly one element.
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not passing url as a command line argument.

Try running program like "java Url < Provide url here >"
e.g. java Url www.google.com

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are running without passing in an argument so arg[0] does not exists.

I would add a check at the very beginning of your program to ensure that an argument array has actually passed in.

Something like:

```
if(args.length>0) {
//Rest of your code here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check first if the args table isn't empty. I recommend to use something like this:

```
    try{
        if(args.length > 0){
            URL url = new URL(args[0]);
            System.out.println("URL is " + url.toString());
            System.out.println("protocol is " + url.getProtocol());
            System.out.println("authority is " + url.getAuthority());
            System.out.println("file name is " + url.getFile());
            System.out.println("host is " + url.getHost());
            System.out.println("path is " + url.getPath());
            System.out.println("port is " + url.getPort());
            System.out.println("default port is " + url.getDefaultPort());
            System.out.println("query is " + url.getQuery());
            System.out.println("ref is " + url.getRef());
        } 
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```